# What will perform better Using .Load() Statement before predicate or just call my predicate after .Include() Statement?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a performance issue and I'm wondering if I have it right.

First I was calling:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> FindByConditionAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression, bool AsNoTracking = true, params string[] includes)
{
    var set = dbSet.AsQueryable();
    if (AsNoTracking)
        set = dbSet.AsNoTracking();
    if (includes != null)
    {
        foreach (var include in includes)
        {
            if (include != null)
                set = set.Include(include);
        }
    }
    var data = set.Where(expression);
    return await data.ToListAsync();
}
```

And every time I include something like `includes:"list"` the response takes longer than 2 seconds.

And I wonder if I use `await set.LoadAsync()` will have any better performance in a long run application like:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> FindByConditionAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression, bool AsNoTracking = true, params string[] includes)
{
    var set = dbSet.AsQueryable();
    if (AsNoTracking)
        set = dbSet.AsNoTracking();
    if (includes != null)
    {
        foreach (var include in includes)
        {
            if (include != null)
                set = set.Include(include);
        }
    }
    await set.LoadAsync();//here

    var data = set.Where(expression);
    return await data.ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: No, that will query without predicate (!) and then another time with it.

Comment: Will i don't usually use ```.Load()``` before predicate but I'm having a stress test and i was testing all other options , Thanks

Comment: have you benchmarked it ?

Comment: use a stop watch, check the results. the problem might be elsewhere

Comment: Whether the data table contains lots of data? "the response takes longer than 2 seconds." Do you mean execute the FindByConditionAsync method will spend 2 seconds, try to add timer to check it?